# VM restoring issue

Tags: vmware-fusion

My VM has apparently crashed, probably due to a virus attack. Here's the message I'm getting

The saved memory file "/Users/fjacks/Desktop/Windows Vista.vmwarevm/Windows Vista.vmem" is corrupt and cannot be restored.

What are my options? This has never happened before. Please, no lectures about windows and viruses. I need a solution, not another problem.

!file:///Users/fjacks/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/moz-screenshot.png!!file:///Users/fjacks/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/moz-screenshot-1.png!

Comment: Just want to mention that it's unlikely this crash was caused by a virus. I've seen this kind of crash before when leaving a snapshot active on a VM for an extended period of time, and there are various other reasons, but I can't see a feasible way for a virus to crash a VM in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

The .vmem file is a copy of the running memory state on the VM and is only present when a VM is running or has crashed. You should be able to restart the machine if the .vmem is corrupt but you wont be able to restore it to the running state. To get around this rename the relevant file to something else (to get past the corruption issue) and try to power on the VM.

When you say "probably due to a virus attack" was this on the guest system or the host? Whichever it was you should seriously consider cleanly rebuilding it and sanitizing all data - anything on the infected system is now highly suspect.